# Best/Logical practice for properties values update (Controller or Service layer?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

My project got Web API Controller, Services and Repositories. Controller got an Update method like:

```
 public IActionResult Update(CreateCollaboratorViewModel collaboratorViewModel)
    {
       //Is it good to set values here in Controller or in Service layer ?

        AdminCollaborators collaborator = new AdminCollaborators();
        collaborator.Description = collaboratorViewModel.Description;
        collaborator.ModifiedBy = _myContext.CurrentUserId;
        var output = _collaboratorService.UpdateCollaborator(collaborator, _myContext.CurrentUserId);
        return Ok(new WebApiResultValue(true, output, "update successful."));
    }
```

**Service**

```
 public AdminCollaborators UpdateCollaborator(AdminCollaborators collaborator, Guid actorUserId)
    {
        collaborator.ModifiedBy = actorUserId;
        collaborator.ModifiedOn = DateTimeHelper.Instance.GetCurrentDate();
        _collaboratorRepository.UpdateCollaborator(collaborator,actorUserId);
        return _collaborationRepository.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Normally Services are supposed to implement business logic (if im not wrong). Please advice should I update the properties values in Controller or Services.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common result of implementing DDD-ish architctures. When domains are too simple, you end up with many layers doing the same thing with more or less level of abstraction each one.

BTW, you go this route because you've determined that some day you'll want to be able to put more complicated things in the right place. Otherwise, you would need to do a massive refactor to turn a non-layered project into a n-layered one.

Anyway, updates should be done in the service layer. Probably, your service layer should look as follows:

```
collaboratorService.Update(collaboratorId, updateCollaboratorDto);
```

Where `updateCollaboratorDto` should be a *DTO* which should come with the data you want to update on your *domain object*.

As of the mapping betweeen a *DTO* and *domain object*, you should use *AutoMapper* to map them all automatically.

Note that you're in a WebAPI/RESTful API world and you're talking about *view models*. I would rename them replacing the *ViewModel* sufix to *Dto*.